# Is preloading images a good practice in html5

Tags: javascript, html, image, performance

I have been working on a new site, and the person who cut it used dreamweaver. It put in mm_preloadimages into the header and uses it on the body. However, it's only loading like 3 of the 30 images on the more complicated pages.

Is preloading a common practice even with more modern html? Or should this be left to the browser to download images.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on your need, according to requirements of the application/project. For example, I did it once for a specific need and it was that, I have used a `hover` effect on by blog using `JavaScript` and when I hovered over the element, it just toggles the image but I realized that, at the first hover it used to take more time to alternate the image because, the image used to be loaded only after the hover on the element and that's why I used image pre-loading technique, so, during the page load, I loaded the image that is going to be used for the hover effect.

So, it's not about common practice but it's about your need, if you really need to pre-load some images then you may use it but if not necessary then just leave it, IMO.

Also, remember that, every time you load an image, it makes an individual `HTTP` request to load the image, so if you load a huge amount of images on the page load, it may slow down the page loading.

Comment: in the particular case I encountered it was preloading images that were part of a slider, and the slider library preloaded anyway. I think this is just a relic of a previous site version.

Comment: @DevelopingChris, For a slider you may use pre-load.

Answer (score 1):

The preloading concept mainly serves for menus that have different background images on mouse hover. You can always use image sprites to have all backgrounds you are using in one single image.

I think the common practice nowadays is to use CSS to style menus and avoid using images at all. If CSS rules cannot satisfy the needs of the design, you can put your images in one using sprites, thus eliminating the need to preload images and avoid having many http requests.